# PostgreSQL foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

how to detect if a column of a table is set by a foreign key, and get the name of the referenced table, in Postgres?

I need this Information for a java GUI. So SQL solution is the best way it could be solved, i really can't manage it.

regards stefan

example:

```
create table SUREALTABLE(
    VNR varchar(5),
    tnumberone integer,
    tnumbertwo integer,
    foreign key (tnumberone ,tnumbertwo) references TESTTABLE(numberone,numbertwo),
    primary key (VNR)
);

create table TESTTABLE(
    numberone integer,
    numbertwo integer,
    primary key (numberone, numbertwo)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine that with `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` and `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` (more info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)).

```
select a.confrelid::regclass,
       b.attname
from pg_constraint a
       join pg_attribute b
         on a.conrelid = b.attrelid
         and b.attnum = any (a.conkey)
where a.conrelid = '<tablename>'::regclass
  and a.contype = 'f'
;
```

You can filter that down using b.attname.

More concrete example:

```
select a.confrelid::regclass
from pg_constraint a
       join pg_attribute b
         on a.conrelid = b.attrelid
         and b.attnum = any (a.conkey)
where a.conrelid = 'SUREALTABLE'::regclass
  and a.contype = 'f'
  and b.attname = 'tnumberone'
;
```

This returns "testtable", indicating that the column "tnumberone" of the table "surealtable" has a foreign key reference to the table "testtable".

Comment: could you please give example how that will look with some variables.. so as an example we have a table named T1 and a table T2. T1 foreign t2.ID references from(t2.id)

Comment: Sure. Can you edit your question to add your schema? Your create table statements would be helpful (you can change the names, just keep the structure the same).

Comment: I added an extra example for you.